# How do I check if a VM already exists via Azure CLI?

Tags: bash, azure, azure-cli

This is a working solution but not very clean:

```
if [ "$(az vm list -d -o table --query "[?name=='VM_NAME']")" == "$(az vm list -d -o table --query "[?name=='ABSURD_NAME_THAT_CERTAINLY_DOES_NOT_EXIST']")" ]; 
then
    printf "VM DOES NOT EXIST YET"
else
    printf "VM ALREADY EXISTS"
fi
```

I couldn't figure out, what
`"$(az vm list -d -o table --query "[?name=='ABSURD_NAME_THAT_CERTAINLY_DOES_NOT_EXIST']")"`
returns which is why I couldn't shorten this solution.
I'm certainly no expert in Bash scripting and I don't know how to convert the result to hexvalues or similar to make it visible.

So I am looking for either a short version of this solution or for another more clean approach. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything like `az vm exists`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution a while ago. The output of the az vm list command if no vm is available is apparently the empty string. But you have to use one equal sign instead of two for the comparison.

```
if [ "$(az vm list -d -o table --query "[?name=='VM_NAME']")" = "" ];
then
    echo "No VM was found."
else
    echo "VM was found."
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use [Azure Graph](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/concepts/explore-resources) in order to do it.

```
az graph query -q "Resources | where type =~'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines' | limit 1"
```

You can see some example [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/samples/advanced?tabs=azure-cli#vm-regex).

```
Resources
| where type =~ 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines' and name matches regex @'^Contoso(.*)[0-9]+$'
| order by name asc
```